# Use "AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" when using Label in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I would like to ask if there is a way to make a Xamarin.Forms.Label tell that it should use the "AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" when the app is run on iOS.

Is this possible, or is Xamarin.Forms.Label something completely different than the UILabel?

I was thinking that Xamarin.Form.Label "falls back" on the UILabel when it's built for iOS, is that the case?

Edit:

According to how I understood the comments I tried this, but it wouldn't work:

```
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                {
                    _label1.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
```

The error I'm getting is that "AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" isn't a property of Xamarin.Forms.Label.

Edit 2:
According to another comment I tried the following:

```
public class clsGridCell : ContentView
{
    private Xamarin.Forms.Label _label1;
    //problem is that it's not longer a Xamarin.Forms.Label, but UILabel on iOS, but I can't declare it as "var" when I want to reuse it for binding. 
    //declaring it as "object" would break the bindings.

    public clsGridCell()
    {

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                {
                    _label1 = new UILabel
                    _label1.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    _label1 = new Xamarin.Forms.Label()
                    {
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    };
                    break;
                }
        }
        this._label1.SetBinding(Label.BackgroundColorProperty, new Binding() { Path = "BackgroundColor", Source = this });
        this._label1.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = "Text", Source = this });
        this._label1.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, new Binding() { Path = "TextColor", Source = this });
```

The error is in line "_label1.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;".
The error thrown is "Label doesn't contain "AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth"".

That is because I declared it as "Label".
I did that because "var" wasn't possible in this case.

What would be an alternative way to declare it without breaking the bindings?
Declaring it as "object" would break the bindings.

Thank you!

Comment: The Form's `Label` uses a iOS renderer that creates a `UILabel`, you can alter its behavior via renderers, behaviors, effects, etc... https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/

Comment: use an Effect to tweak the underlying platform implementation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/introduction/

Comment: @Jason Is it possible to do this with a 1-liner (something like "OnPlatform(AdjustFontSizeToFitWidth, null, null), or do I have to write much code? I'm not as curageous yet to try custom renderers.

Comment: I tried it with "Device.OnPlatform(iOS: () => _label1.Font.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true))" but that wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @tmighty `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` is a property on the label, not the font.

Comment: I've changed that, and I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: if you don't want to use Effects, you could use Native Embedding instead: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/

Comment: @Jason That looks great, but I have to declare the label privately, not in the script. I will edit my post to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SushiHangover mentioned above,there are several ways to achieve your requirement.

- ### Use [Effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/)

  #### In PCL

  ```
  label.Effects.Add (Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.AdjustsFontSizeEffect"));
  ```

  #### Create class named AdjustsFontSizeEffect In iOS Project

  ```
  [assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("MyCompany")]
  [assembly:ExportEffect (typeof(AdjustsFontSizeEffect), "AdjustsFontSizeEffect")]
  namespace EffectsDemo.iOS
  {
      public class AdjustsFontSizeEffect : PlatformEffect
      {
          protected override void OnAttached ()
          {
              (Control as UILabel).AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
          }

          protected override void OnDetached ()
          {

          }
      }
  }
  ```
- ### Use [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

  #### Create class named AdjustsFontSizeEffectRenderer In iOS Project

  ```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(AdjustsFontSizeEffectRenderer))]
  namespace EffectsDemo.iOS
  {
      public class AdjustsFontSizeEffectRenderer : LabelRenderer
      {
          protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
          {
              base.OnElementChanged(e);

              if (Control != null)
              {
                  Control.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I recommend you to use `Effects`in this scenario.

Refer to [Why Use an Effect over a Custom Renderer?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/introduction/#Why_Use_an_Effect_over_a_Custom_Renderer)

Comment: Using your class suggestion, I get the error "UIView doesn't contain a definition for AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" in the line "Control.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;"

Comment: @tmightyeffects or custom renderer？

Comment: CustomRenderer doesn't throw any compiler errors, but it doesn't have any effect. Do I need to "activate" it for it to have an effect on a label?

Comment: @tmighty No need ,you can try backgroundcolor to see if it works or not

Comment: Changing the background color HAS an effect. Does that mean it's not working?

Comment: Perhaps suggestion #1) is the solution to go with, but I don't know how to resolve the error I'm getting ("AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth isn't a property of Control").

Comment: I tried var label = (UILabel)Control along with solution #1); and according to the docs it should work. So I will accept your answer.

Comment: @tmighty okay, I have changed the code  in my answer.